Cable type selection for 128 channel signal transfer
I want to use a cable to be connected (soldered) to my PCB, my PCB has 128 pads on it as follows:

The signal that will be transfer to cable is @3 MHz to 6 MHZ, in range of 150 uA.
The width of the cable that I need to use should be as small as possible. Besides it needs to a have shielding on the cable cover. There should be at least 128 wires inside the cable. My question is can I find something similar to this cable? or I should make it myself? Please let me know your suggestions.

How long will the cable be? It sounds like the sort of thing that might be best addressed using a custom flat-flex circuit.

@ Dave Tweed the length would be maximum 1m.

Forwarding comments from previous question as it seems likely relevant: are the signals single ended or differential? (I notice there's 112 pads in the figure.) How tightly controlled does impedance need to be? What is the source impedance or equivalent circuit? Are the sources approximately equal or will any differ? What is the required isolation between signals?

@ Tim Williams the signal are single ended. We do not considered controlled impedance for this design. the source equivalent circuit is current source (150 uA) in parallel with a 1nF capacitor and 2 Ohm resistor.  There sources are equal but nit identical, there can a bit difference between them. Regarding the isolation, we preferer to minimize cross talk between them.

This needs a connectorized solution.  Unless you consider yourself a top notch solderer, you'll probably start breaking connection or wires while soldering new ones to the PCB.

@ SteveSh thanks for the comment, any idea which connector  and cable can be used?

@Andromeda -  There are lots of connector options out there that would handle 128 signals.  So maybe look for 150 pins to give you some pins for returns.  I don't know about other constraints you may have, such as board size, cost, number of makes/breaks, etc to make a specific recommendation.

Soldering that many wires on a pcb is probably not a good idea - a pcb pad is generally not very mechanically strong and if a wire breaks, it is going to be a pig of a job to resolder especially if the broken wire is towards the middle. Realistically you should use a connector. As for what type of connector and suitable cable, it’s really up to you to search as product recommendations are frowned upon here.
I’d look in the direction of the likes of Hirose, Honda and Molex.
